# Text box changes accordion display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to web development and I'm attempting to change an accordion to active when text is entered within a textbox. I'm also trying to make the content within the accordion required when text is entered.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
//when text box is edited
$("#hardware").on("keyup", function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        //Also needing fields to become required here?

        //displaying accordion
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            active: true
        });

        //displaying accordion
    } else {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            active: false
        });
    }
});

//Functionality of accordian
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true
    });

});
```

```html
Hardware Needed:
<br />&nbsp;
<textarea name="hardware" cols="70" rows="5" maxlength="100" id="hardware"></textarea>
<div id="accordion">
     <h3>Account Distribution</h3>

    <div><font color="##000" , size="-8">Dept.
        <input type="text" name="hardwareDistDept" size="3" />&nbsp;Bus Unit
        <input type="text" name="hardwareDistBus" size="6" />&nbsp;Account
        <input type="text" name="hardwareDistAccount" size="6" />&nbsp;Op Unit
        <input type="text" name="hardwareDistUnit" size="6" />&nbsp;Project
        <input type="text" name="hardwareDistProject" size="6" />&nbsp;Work Id
        <input type="text" name="hardwareDistId" size="6" />&nbsp;Resource
        <input type="text" name="hardwareDistResource" size="6" />
        </font>

    </div>
</div>
```

here it is in fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VmB6T/353/)

According to my thought process the accordion should expand on text input. But it's not... can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to re-write the calls slightly, like this:

```
$("#hardware").on("keyup", function () {
    if ( $(this).val().length > 0 ) {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 0 );
    } else {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", false );
    }
});
```

[**See this updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VmB6T/362/)

Writing it like this:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: true
});
```

Is actually initializing the accordion widget again. The proper way to set the options on a jQuery UI widget, after it has been initialized is by calling it's internal `option` function, like so:

```
$(selector).widget( "option", "optionName", otionValue );
```

And to get it,

```
$(selector).widget( "option", "optionName");
```

Take a look at the [Accordion Option-Active Docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

Answer (score 0):

We have give only index for active property in Accordion.

```
$("#hardware").on("keyup", function () {
    var isActive = ($(this).val().length > 0) ? 0 : false;
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        active : isActive,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VmB6T/365/)

[**For Study More**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_accordion.htm)